# Regexp for cyrillic word doesn't work in app

Tags: javascript, regex, cyrillic

I'm developing web-app with asp.net+js and stuck on regexp which works like a charm small test but absolutely doesn't works as expected in app.

Here's link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=sSzwzBe62Q. 
Here's the example words to try: слово, Слово, Пример. (word, Word, Example - russian).

Code should delete any word except the first one from inputs in left column. It works for latin but doesn't work for cyrillic. Any suggestions?

Perfectly working short example:

```
var rx = /[\wА-Яа-яЁё]+/;
var text = "Слово Word";
document.body.innerHTML = rx.exec(text);
```

Comment: I'm thinking you might have some encoding issues? Try saving the file as unicode.

Comment: @CristiMihai VS uses utf by default. It's not the reason, i think

Comment: The jsfiddle link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @CristiMihai i didn't do anything. Maybe some TTL expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the ranges as unicode ranges.

I'm not very familiar with cyrillic, so I'm going to base my answer on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode:

```
/[\w\u0400-\u04ff\u0500-\u052f\ua640-\ua69f\u1d2b-\u1d78]+/.exec("Слово Word");
```